# SUPER SIMPLE LINQ to filter row does not work

Tags: linq, iqueryable

Spent about 4 hours trying to figure this out without success.

```
IQueryable<userTOM> Infolist =  userTOMs();
        var rbtUserId = Infolist.Where(x => x.UserName == FormsUserName);
```

userTOMs <-- Does not exist. 
Remade the namespace many times but will not appear.

Comment: What is the resulttype of function userTOMs?

Comment: Please mention the from where you define the method userTOMs();

Comment: I want to get the ID from the user's table that corresponds to the FORMS username. all usernames are distinct so just one record will appear.

Comment: I defined them by dragging the tables from server Explorer into the OK interface then I named the user table to  userTOM, saved and built the project.
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34014

Comment: You need to elobarate more to understand the issue. What does not appear? The result or the method or the userId?

Comment: userTOMs   <- is underlined in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IQueryable does not run immediately on the database. In order to run the query, one has to run functions such as `.ToList()`, or `.Count()` on the IQueryable.

Therefore, nothing in your pasted code triggers the database request, and the ID will not be retrieved. I would modify your request to this:

```
IQueryable<userTOM> Infolist =  userTOMs();
userTOM rbtUser = Infolist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == FormsUserName);

Guid rbtUserId; //assuming this will be populated with a Guid value
if (rbtUser != null) {
    rbtUserId = rbtUser.Id; //assuming "ID" is the property name
}
```

Comment: I understand LINQ better now and will use this snippet. Thanks. 
The userTOM is NOT underlined while the userTOMs  is still underlined in RED. :( 
I was hoping that I just needed to add something to the namespace code?

Comment: "The name 'userTOMs' does not exist in the current context "

Comment: Here it is in my class:

  public System.Data.Linq.Table<userTOM> userTOMs
  {
   get
   {
    return this.GetTable<userTOM>();
   }
  }
  
  public System.Data.Linq.Table<MessageStageTOM> MessageStageTOMs
  {
   get
   {

Comment: Well it sounds like `userTOMs` is a table and you use it like a function.. so maybe change to `IQueryable<userTOM> Infolist =  userTOMs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == FormsUserName);` ?

Comment: That did it. THANKS. I did not know the difference..

Comment: @ThomasMahoney Glad to help. Since it's your first question on SO, I'd offer a quick explanation - if you find an answer useful, please upvote it (upper triagle above the number to the left of the question). If you have several answers to your question, or just one that you found useful and that solved your question, please also accept that answer by clicking the tick mark below the score of the answer. That way future visitors would know what helped you :)